# Why is GoogleBuzz missing and certain icons not displaying in my LinkShare?

Tags: html, asp.net, razor, digg, google-buzz

I have this code in my asp.net _SiteLayout.cshtml page:

```
<div id="linkShare">
    @LinkShare.GetHtml(Page.Title, pageLinkBack:"www.dynamash.com", linkSites:LinkShareSite.All)
</div>
```

The "All" member of LinkShareSite should cuase all the sites to display: Deli.ciou.us, Digg, GoogleBuzz, Facebook, Reddit, StumbleUpon, and Twitter.

Yet, as you can see below, only the last four are displaying (the first two have a hint/title of "Deli.ciou.us" and "Digg," respectively, so I assume they are "there," just missing an icon. GoogleBuzz is just flat out MIA, though.

[image]

Why is Buzz missing? How can I get it to display? And how can I get the two missing icons to display?

If this is just a temporary outage, I can live with it, but if Delicious and Digg continue generic, I'll just change the code to exclude them from the party...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mashed F12 with the site running (locally), and found:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://digg.com/img/badges/16x16-digg-guy.gif
```

So, this is why digg won't display - the gif is missing from its expected location.

Also, when I alter my LinkShare to specify the links I want explicitly (rather than selecting "All"), I see that GoogleBuzz is struck out, and marked as obsolete.